# Is there a natural Zariski topology on a general finite dimensional vector space?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras, exterior-algebra, zariski-topology

**General question:**

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space. It is clear that $V\cong \mathbb{F}^{\dim V}=\mathbb{A}_{\mathbb F}^{\dim V}$, and so you might want to give $V$ a Zariski topology based on the linear isomorphism (or equivalently, the basis of $V$). Is there a genral way to do that?

The problem, as I see it, is that you can have many different isomorphisms and therefore different topologies.

**Specific Question:**

I'm reading about lie groups $G$, their associated lie algebras $\mathfrak{g}$, and the exterior algebra $\Lambda^d(\mathfrak{g})$ for some $d\leq \dim \mathfrak{g}$. In a paper I'm reading, there is a use (without explanation) of the terms of Zariski topology regarding $\Lambda^d(\mathfrak{g})$. What is the correct interpretation of this?

Comment: My hunch is that the induced topology is the same no matter which isomorphism you choose

Comment: @Omnomnomnom One can define a polynomial on $V$ to be a member of $S(V^*)$ (i.e. the symmetric algebra on the algebraic dual of $V$). This is basis independent, and hence gives a basis independent definition of the Zariski topology.

Comment: @OscarCunningham Magical!  Thanks for that.

Comment: Anyway nothing magic is needed to show that if $P$ is a polynomial on $K^n$ and $f$ is a linear automorphism of $K^n$, then $P\circ f$ is also a polynomial, and hence the Zariski topology does not depend on a choice of basis.